# Retrieve records in a range using year and month fields in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a mysql table with year (`YEAR(4)`) and month (`TINYINT`) columns. What is the best way to select all records in a range, e.g. 2009-10 .. 2010-02 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a generalized solution:

```
Select...
From ...
Where ( Year = <StartYear> And Month >= <StartMonth> )
    Or ( Year > <StartYear> And Year < <EndYear> )
    Or ( Year = <EndYear> And Month <= <EndMonth> )
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
WHERE (year = 2009 AND month >= 10)
   OR (year = 2010 AND month <= 2)
```

...or, using UNION ALL:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM TABLE t
 WHERE year = 2009 AND month >= 10
UNION ALL
SELECT t.*
  FROM TABLE t
 WHERE year = 2010 AND month <= 2
```

`UNION ALL` is faster than `UNION`, but won't remove duplicates.

Comment: But what if you have from October 2007 to February 2010? You cannot just substitute the dates.

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo: I would store the values as DATETIME, which would alleviate complications for queries like what you suggest.  If needed, I'd create a view to break out the day/month/year.

Comment: @OMG: Yes, DATETIME would be ideal, but I think the OP does not have a DAY value. Just month and year.

Comment: @Daniel: That is your assumption, not fact.

Comment: Let's consider it an "educated guess" :)

Comment: @OMG,@Daniel There's no 'day' in the table. Every record represents a period of month, for example 2010-02. If I use a single `DATE` column, it would be 2010-02-00 which seems a bit strange.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider creating another column called `year_month` which stores the date in `YYYYMM` format, such as `201002` for February 2010. Make sure to create an index on it, and you may also create two triggers to automatically update the column ON INSERT and ON UPDATE.

Then you would be able to use:

```
WHERE year_month BETWEEN 200710 AND 201002
```

This would use the index on `year_month`.

Comment: just a note that year_month is a reserved word in mysql and cannot be used as column name. Please refer to the doc: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer does not work for the case when StartYear and EndYear is the same. E.g. 2017-01 to 2017-08. A revised psuedocode that covers this case would be

((year = StartYear and month >= StartMonth) OR (year > StartYear)) AND ((year = EndYear and month <= EndMonth) OR (year < EndYear))

Comment: 1701 is not the same as 1710.

Comment: Clarified the example, I meant 2017-01 (Jan) and 2017-10 (Oct), which is an example case of where it fails.